# How to convert string with any date format to %m/%d/%y in Python

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a csv with with dates. The dates have inconsistent formatting and I want it all to change to `mm/dd/yyyy` upon importing. Is there a way to do it? I know about `strptime` but that requires a second argument for the format of the given date.

Comment: post some example how that inconsistant dates looks  like?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `strftime` from `datetime` with this you can perform a format change without the given format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).